# jQuery doesn't work in Blackberry OS 5? Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I did a small javascript program for BlackBerry OS 5, using jQuery. Unfortunately, when trying in actual device, those functions are not executed:

```
$(".colorboard").css("background-color","#FF0000");
$(id).unbind('click');
$(id).bind('click', function(event){ alert("hello!")});
$(id).html(mytext);
```

Why it does not work? There are alternatives that will work on BB OS 5? I tried zepto.js but no luck.

Comment: As I know, From O.S 6.0 onwards 90% of javascript and JQuery is worked well; In 5.0 No JQuery as well as javaScript code is wored;

Comment: on OS5 javascript is disabled by default in the browser, but it is enabled in webworks apps

Comment: For Blackberry webworks you should have atleast 6.0 not 5.0 then how can you say that javascript is enable for webworks;

Comment: I tried on real device, webworks works on 5.0, js is enabled, I am 100% sure, some functions are loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part where it failed:

```
$(".colorboard").css("background-color","#FF0000");
```

So far I also didn't know how to support it, even jQuery mobile theme give-up on this problem.
Please refer to [this post](http://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699568/jquery-show-and-blackberry-os5&ei=IE2_T7S9D6z06AHrxazACg&usg=AFQjCNEFEuEfaPzJgU7Q2DeiH9Z7VtYFrg&sig2=xvdBeETFTOaRNOD92kPb6g) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For BB OS5 use every time the element tag name with a class like this:

```
$("div.colorboard").css("background-color","#FF0000");
```